# File line into lists delimited by a specific string (sharp #) and add the line before

Tags: python-3.x, list

This is the content of my file :

```
#Stream Number 51 #  
#944_testing_1)#  
Data1  
133  
124  
FRE  
new  
Cable  
Sat  
#Stream Number 555 #    
#94_fr_change#     
DataB  
233  
445  
DEU  
Old  
Sat  
#Stream Number 45 #  
#822_Sports_(FR)# 
MyValue  
4566  
455  
ITA  
NEW
```

What I need is to put each of them into a list and the separator must be the #, I also need the line before :

the result here must be :

```
mylist1=["#944_testing_1)#","Data1","133","124","FRE","new","Cable","Sat"]
mylist2=["#94_fr_change#","DataB","233","445","DEU","Old","Sat"]
```

I don't want the line that contain #Stream Number etc... and the length of the file can be variable.

What I do until today is :

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    master_list = []
    lst = []
    for i in data:
        if '#' in i:
            master_list.append(lst)
            lst = []
        else:
            lst.append(i.replace('\n', ''))


master_list[1:]

['Data1', '133', '124', 'FRE', 'new', 'Cable', 'Sat'], ['DataB', '233', '445', 'DEU', 'Old', 'Sat'], ['MyValue', '4566', '455', 'ITA', 'NEW'], ['MyValue5', '455', '22332', 'Eng', 'Sat', 'Cable']]
```

But I miss the value of of the line before like : #944_testing_1)#, #94_fr_change#"

Comment: Use `line.startswith('#Stream')` then append the lst to master_list if lst exists

Comment: I don't want the line who start with #Stream but the one with #944 (#and a number)

Comment: That is what is happening in if-case. The line is not added to lst, earlie formed lst is added to master_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the thing I was trying to tell you in comment here.

```
master_list = []
lst = []
for item in data:
    print(item)
    if item.startswith('#Stream'):
        if lst:
            master_list.append(lst)
            lst = []
    else:
        lst.append(item)
if lst:
    master_list.append(lst)

print(master_list)
```

which gives me:

```
[['#944_testing_1)#  ', 'Data1 ', '133  ', '124  ', 'FRE  ', 'new  ', 'Cable ', 'Sat  '], ['#94_fr_change#     ', 'DataB ', '233  ', '445  ', 'DEU  ', 'Old  ', 'Sat  '], ['#822_Sports_(FR)# ', 'MyValue', '4566', '455', 'ITA', 'NEW']]
```